# Proving that a statement about $<$ is valid

Tags: logic, inequality

I need to do assignment for my homework, in which I need to prove that the following statement is valid.
$$
(s<t \text{ and } t<u)\implies(s<u)
$$

I need to do this assignment using the laws and definitions of inequality.

The problem is that I don't know how to do it.

Can somebody point me in the right direction, how to use the laws and definitions, to solve this.

I am NOT asking from you to solve this for me, I am just asking you, to give me some reference so I can do this on my own.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "the laws and definitions of inequality"? Usually, this *is* one of the laws of inequality, so it would be a good thing if you [edit] your post to include your laws and definitions.

Comment: The problem is that I dont know what they are. I gt my homework assignment with email, and the assignment were there. No laws or definitions of inequality. So I am trying to do that now how I can.

Comment: Check your notes and/or textbook. Without some context, there isn't much we can do for you. :-(

Comment: Are there some general laws and definitions of inequality I can use???

Comment: Yes, but as I said, the thing you're supposed to prove usually **is** a law of inequality, so there's nothing to prove. This leads me to believe that you've been given some laws/definitions already, which do *not* include this one. See if you can find them.

Comment: Here are a few keywords that may help: "irreflexive," "asymmetric," "transitive."

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I will look trough textbook, if I can find something. If I stumble in an problem, I will ask here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that

$$a  <b\implies a - b < 0\;\;\text{and}\;\; b < c \implies b-c < 0$$

$$\begin{align} \quad a - b &\lt 0\\
+\;\;b - c &\lt 0\\
\hline \\
(a-b) + (b - c) &\lt 0 \\ \\
a - c \lt 0 \implies & \cdots \end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Well actually you define real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ a set for which your inequality is valid. Is called transitive property. As stated in previous comments.

Comment: +1, but technically transitivity is a property of the binary relation $<$ and not the underlying set $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What I meant is that as soon as you are dealing with numbers $x\in \mathbb{R}$ the property holds.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use something like the following: If there exists a number between $a$ and $b$, then either $a < b$ or $b < a$. Use this fact along with the given inequalities to show that only one of these two cases is possible.